# Unable to redeem some "Games with Gold" titles with an active subscription

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network

I recently purchased an Xbox One and haven't been able to redeem the backwards compatible Xbox 360 (Dragon Age II) and original Xbox games (Mercenaries: Playground of Destruction). Participating Xbox One games have games have been added to my account so far, but the legacy games display a price.

To my knowledge all games given for the Gold subscribers run on Xbox One and don't require legacy hardware to redeem -- [Xbox Live for the original Xbox was discontinued in 2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20101125060201/http://majornelson.com/archive/2010/02/05/xbox-live-being-discontinued-for-original-xbox-consoles-and-games.aspx).

Comment: see [this recent Reddit discussion on /r/xboxone](https://old.reddit.com/r/xboxone/comments/a6ao3f/mercenaries_now_free_with_gold/) about Mercenaries: Playground of Destruction (2005, Xbox)

Comment: I'm not sure if [this comment](https://old.reddit.com/r/xboxone/comments/a6ao3f/mercenaries_now_free_with_gold/ebtb46w/?st=jpudcfkt&sh=37283744) is from you as well, but I'd keep an eye on it if anyone else submits a response there.

Comment: @ChaseIngebritson: The new batch of games hadn't yet arrived (in all regions) when that comment was written. I however found [another comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/xboxone/comments/a6ao3f/mercenaries_now_free_with_gold/ebu3sey/): "MS really need to let you download the 360 and original xbox GwG without having payment details on your account." — I haven't intentionally saved my payment information to avoid unwanted charges, but I will try redeeming with payment details saved soon.